# Maintain an iframe context

Tags: php

My first post here! My question relates to iframes and php mostly

So... it's impossible for PHP to check if a page was requested through an iframe. This question seems to be asked (and answered) a lot, but would it be possible to create an "iframe context" and maintain that context throughout the navigation within an iframe?

For example :

```
<iframe src="/my/url?location=iframe"></iframe>
```

we could initially check if ($_GET['location'] == 'iframe')

however, as navigation goes on, you can imagine what happens. Links are click, forms are submitted, and they don't necessarily have ?location=iframe.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to create an initial context that begins with the url parameter above and persists within the iframe only.

Just to be clear, in my example the iframe contains pages from the same site.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can make in php a function that gives you the url and use it each time you present a url. that function will take a url and if iframe is set in `$_GET` it will append that to the url, or leave it as is if iframe isn't set. be sure to use it on every link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set the initial URL to `/iframe/my/url` when it's loaded in an iframe, and `/my/url` when it isn't, and either:

- Create a symlink (or an NTFS junction) in your document root called 'iframe' that points to your document root and parse `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`
- use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite the URL so it points to the right place and has the `location=iframe` or maybe `#iframe` tagged onto it

The first option is probably the best, although all your paths would have to relative. This means all your paths will stay within the `/iframe/` path and you never need to alter your links - everything is processed for you.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into this. Will let you know.

Comment: This is it! I'll have to adapt, but this it it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could put this in a document ready function and add #iframe as a hash to all links on the page. then use php to check for the hash

```
$('a').each(function(){
    this.attr('href',this.attr('href')+'#iframe');
});
```

Comment: Not a good idea to rely on JS for your core site functionality - what if the user turns it off/is blocking it? JS can make things nicer, but it shouldn't be required to make them work at all... Plus, what about forms? What about images? What about iframe-specific JS/CSS?

Comment: i was thinking that when i wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it's true, I'm looking for a non-js solution.

Comment: you could set it up so that when the iframe first loads, it sends a message to the php script telling it that its the iframe (ex: yoursite.com/iframe.php) and then from there on out the php could do basically the same thing as i suggested with javascript